# Find number of items in a dataset

Tags: count

When trying to find the number of times a word is repeated in a dataset... for example if one column has East Northeast and West, and I am trying to find how many Northeasts there are?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? What language are you using? What is a code snippet of what the dataset looks like and how you are consuming it? There is not enough information in this question to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
const column = ['east', 'west', 'northeast', 'west', 'northeast', 'south'];

const frequency = column.filter(word => word === 'northeast').length
```

the value of `frequency` here is 2

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(column) FROM dataset WHERE column LIKE '%Northeast%'
```

C#:

```
int count = dataSet.dataTable[0].AsEnumerable()
           .Count(row => row.Field<string>("Column-A") == "Northeast");
```